# What is appropriate format for Google places phone number?

Tags: google, google-places

For google places phone number, what is the best format?

```
+1 604-221-6684 
+1 (604)-221-6684 
604-221-6684 
(604)-221-6684 
6042216684
```

I mean logically, the last option would be best, because some forms on some website may only allow integer fields (numbers only), so if you use (, + or -, you may limit where you can submit citations?

[image]

Comment: "This entry can only contain numbers."   Doesn't that answer the question?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller raises a good point :)

Comment: No, I have to choose the number format for my citations, some websites may have numbers only fields, integer fields for input, so if I have other characters than digits, it won't work. This question is not for that particular form, it's only an example

Comment: Will you have international customers? That will determine whether you need to include the +1.

Comment: That's actually a very good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about Google My Business (replacement for "Google Places") then the answer is pretty straightforward.

In this example you can see that they represent the number in their database with the +16042216684 format, but in the frontend they show it as (604)-221-6684

For our my clients, I've entered it as (XXX)-XXX-XXXX into Google My Business, and Google is smart enough to convert it to the proper format when needed.

I think it's fair to say either (604)-221-6684 or +16042216684 should work for citations. Just depends on what type of characters they allow.

[image: Phone number in a google result]